# Remove text background with google script ( manually done by format > paragraph> borders and shading > reset )

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1VrkXwfR24nIkX9KEGquIqFgkqPAke6MDst_N7YgSOY0/edit?usp=sharing

this is a sample doc
what i am attempting to do is automize the flow of pressing:  format> paragraph>borders and shading>reset

the goal is to reset the documents white background which aparrently is done via borders and shading

so to conclude i want to :
1.create the code
2.run the code on google app script and see that it works
3.add it as an add on lets focus on 1- 2

I attempted :

I attempted :

```
function resetParagraphFormatting() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  
  var paragraphs = body.getParagraphs();
  for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
    var paragraph = paragraphs[i];
    paragraph.setAttributes({
      "BORDER_WIDTH": 0,
      "BORDER_COLOR": null,
      "BACKGROUND_COLOR": null
    });
  }
}
```

we executes in action script but it doesn't affect the doc when i run it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought that in your situation when Google Docs API is used, the script might be simple. So, in this answer, I would like to propose to achieve your goal using Google Docs API. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Google Docs API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function resetParagraphFormatting() {
  const docId = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId();
  const obj = Docs.Documents.get(docId).body.content;
  Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({ requests: [{ updateParagraphStyle: { range: { startIndex: 1, endIndex: obj.pop().endIndex }, fields: "borderBetween,borderBottom,borderTop,borderLeft,borderRight,shading", paragraphStyle: {} } }] }, docId);
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run, the properties of "Borders and shading" are reset as follows.

[image]

#### Note:

- If you want to also reset the spaces of the paragraph, please include the fields of `spaceAbove,spaceBelow` into `fields: "borderBetween,borderBottom,borderTop,borderLeft,borderRight,shading"`.

#### References:

- [Method: documents.get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get)
- [Method: documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)

Comment: Thanks this code works ! any chance you can explain how to transform it to an add on on google docs ?

Comment: @Amichai Oron Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `any chance you can explain how to transform it to an add on on google docs ?`, I would like to recommend posting it as a new question. By this, it will help users think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?